# How to implement a modal TreeView in ASP.NET MVC / Razor

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I've inherited an ASP.NET MVC project that has UI elements that populate a drop-down list from a database. The `.cshtml` for the data entry element is:

```
        <div class="data-input-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.SourceTag)
            @Html.EditorFor(m => m.SourceTag, new { htmlAttributes = new { list = "source-tag-list", style = "width: 750px" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.SourceTag)
        </div>
        <datalist id="source-tag-list"></datalist>
```

There is some script that populates source-tag-list via a script helper controller which fetches the data from the database. This results in:

```
        <div class="data-input-group">
            <label for="SourceTag">Source Tag Name</label>
            <input class="text-box single-line valid" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Source Tag Name field is required." id="SourceTag" list="source-tag-list" name="SourceTag" style="width: 750px" type="text" value="" aria-describedby="SourceTag-error" aria-invalid="false">
            <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="SourceTag" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
        </div>
        <datalist id="source-tag-list">
        <option value="This is drop down level 1.This is drop down level 2."></option>
        </datalist>
```

Which ends up looking like this:

[image]

(I have no idea how the above HTML ends up as a drop-down list - I inherited this project and I'm very new to ASP.NET MVC, cshtml, jscript, jQuery, etc.)

What I would like to to is replace the drop-down list with a pop-up Tree View. As each node in the tree is expanded, I want to trigger some script that would read the next level of data from the database.

I'm more than happy to have the single-line text box as a text entry box with a 'browse' button next to it if that is easiest to implement

Answer (score 0):

try to implement this treeview https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Implement-TreeView-in-ASPNet-MVC.aspx
I used and is very simple to understand